# Filtering the list of objects using the Map in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, dictionary, data-structures, jvm

I am trying to create a dictionary filter that will filter the incoming list of parameters.
The problem is that when there are parameters in the list that should be filtered and removed - I get a NullPointerException.
Basic informations:
This is how filter looks:

```
data class Filter(
    val filters: Map<ParameterName, Set<String>>
)

data class ParameterName(
    val key: String
)
```

Example of filter:

```
Filter(filters={ParameterName(key=Manufacturer)=[brand, producer]})
```

The filtered list (`List<Parameter>`) has the following structure:

```
data class Parameter(
    val id: String?,
    val name: String?,
    val values: List<String>?
)
```

Example of `List<Parameter>`

```
[Parameter(id=123, name=brand, values=[Nike]), Parameter(id=345, name=color, values=[black, pink]), Parameter(id=823, name=test, values=[some, thing])]
```

The logic is that the filtered list is changed to Map <String, ParameterValue>. Where:
a) String (key) is the value of the filter key (The key in the filter map has the main value and any other names under it. For example - under Manufacturer we have got values "brand" or "producer")

b) The parameter value (e.g. Nike) is assigned to the ParameterValue object (val value: String).

What have I prepared:

```
        fun filterParameters(
            parametersList: List<Parameter>,
            filters: Map<ParameterName, Set<String>>
        ): Map<String, ParameterValue> {
            return parametersList.associate { param ->
                filters.filter {
                    it.value.first().equals(param.name, ignoreCase = true)
                }.keys.first().key to ParameterValue(value = param.values!!.first())
            }.toMap()
        }
```

Flow example:

1. Input to the method:
   a) Parameters list:

```
        listOf(
            Parameter(
                "123",
                "brand",
                listOf("Nike")
            ),
            Parameter(
                "345",
                "color",
                listOf("black", "pink")
            ),
            Parameter(
                "823",
                "test",
                listOf("some", "thing")
            )
        )
```

b) Filter:

```
        mapOf(
            ParameterName("Manufacturer") to setOf("brand", "producer")
        )
```

2)Expected output:

```
{Manufacturer=ParameterValue(value=Nike)}
```

Expected output structure:

```
Map<String, ParameterValue>
```

where

```
data class ParameterValue(
val parameterId: String? = null,
val value: String,
val valueId: String? = null
```

)

So we just fill value - String

Comment: Can you show more examples? What if the filter was `ParameterName("A") to setOf("color")` or `ParameterName("A") to setOf("brand", "color")` or what if there are multiple parameter names with the same set like `ParameterName("A") to setOf("brand"), ParameterName("B") to setOf("brand")`, or what if the set is empty like `ParameterName("A") to setOf()`?

Comment: 1) Why the data class _ParameterName_? A String would do.
2) Why the data class _Filter_? A Map would do.

Comment: The incoming data are created in such a way that the parameters that I will have to save will always be the only value in the set (eg ```ParameterName ("Author") to setOf ("Murakami")``` For example - the producer will always be one, the author will also be one etc. If eg Brand parameter will be duplicated - I save the first If the value for the searched key is empty - I write null.

Comment: Such requirements were imposed. I can't change it.

Comment: Are the data classes your code? Meaning could you change them?

Comment: If the change does not change the business logic and I have arguments to defend it - then yes, but only Filter class. Rest - not. (
in short - I can try to convince to change the structure on Filter to ``` <String, Set <String>>```)

Comment: A data class with one property is usually superfluous. _data class ParameterName(val key: String)_ is nothing else than a _String_. And _data class Filter(val filters: Map<ParameterName, Set<String>>)_ is nothing else than a _Map<String, Set<String>>_.

Comment: Then I will try to output the solution  Map<String, Set <String>>. Unfortunately, even in this form, I do not know how to meet the business requirements (create a filtering method)

Comment: Ok. Next question: in the _data class Parameter_ do all three properties need to be nullable?

Comment: Yes. Data comes from multiple sources and tends to be incomplete.

Comment: But when a _Parameter_ instance is built, does your code add for example for a missing _id_ _null_ or "" (an empty string)? Same question for name. And for missing information for the property _values_: do you add _null_ or _emptyList()_?

Comment: null for id and name.  emptyList() for values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data class Parameter(
  val id: String?,
  val name: String?,
  val values: List<String>?
)

val parameters = listOf(
  Parameter("123", "brand", listOf("Nike")),
  Parameter("3433", "color", listOf("red", "black")),
  Parameter("22313", "model", listOf("air max")),
  Parameter("2312", "origin", listOf("USA")),
  Parameter(null, "size", listOf("7", "7.5", "8", "9")),
  Parameter("987", null, listOf("lalala")),
  Parameter("999", "code", null),
  Parameter(null, null, null)
)

val filters = mapOf(
  "Manufacturer" to setOf("brand", "producer"),
  "Country" to setOf("origin", "from")
)

fun getValuesForParameterName(parameters: List<Parameter>, filters: Map<String, Set<String>>): Map<String, List<String>> {
  return parameters
    .filter { parameter -> parameter.name in filters.flatMap { map -> map.value } }
    .map { parameter -> filters.filter { map -> map.value.contains(parameter.name) }.keys.first() to parameter.values }
    .groupBy { (name, _) -> name }
    .map { (name, values) -> name to values.map { (_, list) -> list ?: emptyList() }.flatten() }
    .toMap()
}

val result = getValuesForParameterName(parameters, filters)
println(result)                   // Output: {Manufacturer=[Nike], Property=[USA]}
println(result["Manufacturer"])   // Output: [Nike]
println(result["Country"])        // Output: [USA]
```

Comment: The incoming parameter list is always for one product. For example: Nike shoes. Parameter List:
`Size - [7,7.5,8,9],
Color - [Black, white, yellow, red],
Producer- [Nike],
Model - [Air max],
Made in - [USA]`  Filtering result is saved in `Map<String, ParameterValue>`, where ParameterValue holds parameter name (e.g. Nike).  ParameterValue structure is `(val parameterId: String? = null,
    val value: String?)` Right now i fill only value field

Comment: Your question is really a mess. So next step: are the multiple _filters_ as indicated at the start of my code?

Comment: Example: List I want to filter: 
`        listOf(
            Parameter(
                "123",
                "brand",
                listOf("Nike")
            ),
            Parameter(
                "3433",
                "color",
                listOf("red", "black")
            ),
            Parameter(
                "22313",
                "model",
                listOf("air max")
            ),
            Parameter(
                "2312",
                "origin",
                listOf("USA")
            )
        )
`

Comment: Filter I use: 
`       mapOf(
            "Manufacturer" to setOf("brand", "producer"),
            "Country" to setOf("origin", "from")
        )`

Comment: Solution I expect : 
Map of <String, ParameterValue> where : 
String key: "Manufactuer", value for this : ParameterValue(value="Nike"),  
String key: "Country", value for this: ParameterValue(value="USA").
So as method signature shows - the result of this should be Map<String, ParameterValue>

Comment: Edited the code. Note that _ParameterValue_ is also a superfluous class. It is a String.

Comment: In this case - I cant. It have to be ParameterValue (this data class have got also additional field that is not filled in this scenario)

Comment: The returned data structure from the method must be Map <String, ParameterValue>

Comment: Anyway - I adapted your solution to my problem. Thank you very much for your help and sorry for all the confusion.